# Change number in a character when reading columns

Tags: fortran

I have an input file that looks like:

```
text
6
    1w    1     3.450   1.324   2.915
    1w    2     3.450   1.324   2.915
    4w    2     3.458   1.379   2.837
    4w    1     3.458   1.379   2.837
    7w    2     3.364   1.345   2.951
    7w    2     3.364   1.345   2.951
```

and I want the output file to look like:

```
text
6
    1w    N      3.450   1.324   2.915
    1w    H1     3.450   1.324   2.915
    4w    H2     3.458   1.379   2.837
    4w    N      3.458   1.379   2.837
    7w    H1     3.364   1.345   2.951
    7w    HW2    3.364   1.345   2.951
```

For the second column, the numbers `1 2 2 1 2 2`, I need to print `"N"` for `1` and `"H1"` and `"H2"` for `2` and than again `NH1H2`, so I mean to tell the program to change once 2 for H1 and then H2. I used

```
if(p==1)p="N"
if(p==2)p="H1"
```

but I have no idea how to put do cycle to tell the second 2 is H2 not H1. Can you suggest what to do?

Comment: Yes, as you are saying. I am trying to read number and write a string instead of it, but for H1 and H2 I have number 2. And I need for each row to change first for H1 and then H2. IHow to get program here, so it is in the way it should be? I tried, but it did not work.

Comment: I tried, but it did not print one line after another line. Is there a specific way to put the code here?

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake, it should be H2. I am not using reading a file in arrays, so the code down is more complicate to use. Do you know easier way when I read without arrays, just simply read(12,*) ... write(11, fmt='(a2,i1,f8.3)')?

Comment: Well correct your question, don't expect anyone to read comments to properly understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to keep a running count of the `H` elements, something like

```
program p
  implicit none
  
  character(2), allocatable :: element_symbols(:)
  
  character(100) :: text
  integer :: no_elements
  character(2) :: name
  integer :: element_id
  character(2) :: element_symbol
  real :: x,y,z
  
  integer :: h_count
  
  integer :: i,input
  
  ! The elemental symbols, so 1->"N", 2->"H" etc.
  element_symbols = ['N', 'H']
  
  h_count = 0
  
  open(10, file='input.dat')
  open(11, file='output.dat')
  
  read(10,*) text
  write(11,*) text
  read(10,*) no_elements
  write(11,*) no_elements
  
  do i=1,no_elements
    read(10,*) name, element_id, x, y, z
    
    element_symbol = element_symbols(element_id)
    
    if (element_symbol=="N") then
      ! If the element is `N`, reset h_count.
      h_count = 0
    elseif (element_symbol=="H") then
      ! If the element is `H`, update h_count.
      h_count = h_count + 1
      write(element_symbol,'(A,I0)') trim(element_symbol), h_count
    endif
    
    write(11,*) name, element_symbol, x, y, z
  enddo
end program
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but I am not using arrays to read and write columns, and so when combined for the column I got ^A^@^@^@. Is there any easier way to get the format without arrays?

Comment: It's hard to know what you'd find easier without knowing exactly what you're doing :) Could you give us the code you are using?

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I see my code is messy, I must adjust it.